# How to compare two images?

Tags: c#, .net

```
public void winCheck()
{
    if (button1.Image == img1)
    {
        w1 = "P2";
        button1.Image = new Bitmap(@"win_cross.png");
        button2.Image = new Bitmap(@"win_cross.png");
        button3.Image = new Bitmap(@"win_cross.png");
    }
}
```

Here both `button1.Image` and `img1` have same image but still, the control doesn't go into the `if` block.
Is their any property of both such that value of both will be same.

Comment: Are you trying to say that the image are the same because they are bit per bit identical (they show the same image)? How do you initialize the button1.Image and the img1 variable?

Comment: Actually they are the same image bit per bit , i have intialized the button1.Image in button1 click event handler and i created img1(Image)(public) variable in the main class itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing Images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412778/comparing-images)

Comment: Thisn is very poor coding to rely on graphical element to hold states and test these states. You should instead define an enumeration for the various states, have a field typed with this enum, and define a method that refreshes your controls image depending on the field enum value.

Comment: This is a nice example: http://www.dotnetexamples.com/2012/07/fast-bitmap-comparison-c.html

Answer (score 9):

Here is one possibility to do it, if you can have `unsafe` code and if you want images to be exactly the same on byte level:

```
public unsafe static bool AreEqual(Bitmap b1, Bitmap b2)
{
    if (b1.Size != b2.Size)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (b1.PixelFormat != b2.PixelFormat)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (b1.PixelFormat != PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
    {
        return false;
    }

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, b1.Width, b1.Height);
    BitmapData data1
        = b1.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, b1.PixelFormat);
    BitmapData data2
        = b2.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, b1.PixelFormat);

    int* p1 = (int*)data1.Scan0;
    int* p2 = (int*)data2.Scan0;
    int byteCount = b1.Height * data1.Stride / 4; //only Format32bppArgb 

    bool result = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < byteCount; ++i)
    {
        if (*p1++ != *p2++)
        {
            result = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    b1.UnlockBits(data1);
    b2.UnlockBits(data2);

    return result;
}
```

This compares images "literally" - all bytes need to be exactly the same. Other possibility would be to compare colours of pixels - then `PixelFormat`s wouldn't have to be the same (taken from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9299/Comparing-Images-using-GDI)):

```
public static CompareResult Compare(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2)
{
    CompareResult cr = CompareResult.ciCompareOk;

    //Test to see if we have the same size of image
    if (bmp1.Size != bmp2.Size)
    {
        cr = CompareResult.ciSizeMismatch;
    }
    else
    {
        //Sizes are the same so start comparing pixels
        for (int x = 0; x < bmp1.Width 
             && cr == CompareResult.ciCompareOk; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < bmp1.Height 
                         && cr == CompareResult.ciCompareOk; y++)
            {
                if (bmp1.GetPixel(x, y) != bmp2.GetPixel(x, y))
                    cr = CompareResult.ciPixelMismatch;
            }
        }
    }
    return cr;
}
```

This can be however very slow. The same link contains an interesting idea of comparing hash values:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace Imagio
{
    public class ComparingImages
    {
        public enum CompareResult
        {
            ciCompareOk,
            ciPixelMismatch,
            ciSizeMismatch
        };

        public static CompareResult Compare(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2)
        {
            CompareResult cr = CompareResult.ciCompareOk;

            //Test to see if we have the same size of image
            if (bmp1.Size != bmp2.Size)
            {
                cr = CompareResult.ciSizeMismatch;
            }
            else
            {
                //Convert each image to a byte array
                System.Drawing.ImageConverter ic = 
                       new System.Drawing.ImageConverter();
                byte[] btImage1 = new byte[1];
                btImage1 = (byte[])ic.ConvertTo(bmp1, btImage1.GetType());
                byte[] btImage2 = new byte[1];
                btImage2 = (byte[])ic.ConvertTo(bmp2, btImage2.GetType());

                //Compute a hash for each image
                SHA256Managed shaM = new SHA256Managed();
                byte[] hash1 = shaM.ComputeHash(btImage1);
                byte[] hash2 = shaM.ComputeHash(btImage2);

                //Compare the hash values
                for (int i = 0; i < hash1.Length && i < hash2.Length 
                                  && cr == CompareResult.ciCompareOk; i++)
                {
                    if (hash1[i] != hash2[i])
                        cr = CompareResult.ciPixelMismatch;
                }
            }
            return cr;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because you are comparing the variables pointing to the images (i.e. in memory address) not the image data (pixels).

See ImageComparer.Compare method. Has overloads to specify tolerance.
It is available since VS2012.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.imagecomparer.compare.aspx

Answer (score -7):

dont use double equal (==). 
use equals method. 
(if button1.Image.equals(img1))
// you code

Comment: -1: Bitmap does not implement "Equals". It compares references by default.

Comment: it's giving a NullReferenceException - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: then one of your image is null. check for it @k3rn3l

Comment: @AsadAli Why don't you test it yourself? **Bitmap b1 = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(fname);
            Bitmap b2 = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(fname);
            var isEqual = b1.Equals(b2);**