# if (pictureBox1.Image == ProjectName.Properties.Resources.Q)

Tags: c#, if-statement, equals, picturebox

I have issue in my code, it doesn't works, look at code:
What is wrong? I've found this:

```
if (pictureBox1.Image.Equals(Q))
{
    --stav;
}
```

It should do something like this

```
if (pictureBox1.Image == ProjectName.Properties.Resources.Q)
{

}
```

My question is, how to make something like if (pictureBox1.Image == ProjectName.....)
Thanks

PROBLEM SOLVED!

Comment: another question on [comparing images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647811/comparing-two-images-in-c-sharp)

Comment: What is exactly the question? what do u want to achieve? compare an image to a string? please give more detail

Comment: At least you where added some effort on title and question formulation....

Comment: Edited it, now there is briefly written the question.

Answer (score 1):

`Resources.SomeProperty`  lets say `SomeProperty` is an `Image` will always return a new instance. So they are different references.

`Image` class doesn't overloads `==` operator. So `==` will result in Reference comparison, which is never going to be true for different references.

`Image.Equals` method also won't work as it doesn't override `Equals` so once again Reference comparison will be used.

You need your own Image comparison algorithm if you need to compare it. You'd do it by comparing pixel by pixel.

Comment: I don't want to compare image, i want to compare image source.

ex. compare if right now used image (compare as file address) is same  as ProjectName.Properties.Resources.Image

Got it? I want to compare file path. Not pixel by pixel.

Comment: What does that even mean? When you have `Image` object alone you can't find where does it comes from. Can you explain some more what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: `ProjectName.Properties.Resources.Image` is not a file path. It is also a property which returns `Image`. That is also a object. My answer still stands, If you want to compare which images you need to compare  pixel by pixel only. Another workaround will be store the name of the property you get the image in a string field, then you can check that string field to see where you got the image. Otherwise you can't do that. There is no way to find where you got the `Image` object from.

Comment: [link] http://i.epvpimg.com/4Frie.png [/link]

Comment: So how can i compare if image used by pictureBox1 is image from resources? Another way than pixel by pixel? Please briefly.