# How to compare two images between a PictureBox and a resource data?

Tags: c#, image, winforms, compare, picturebox

So I have a picturebox and I need to check what image it's currently displaying so I can put it in an if statement.
Basically "if pictureBox1 image is diamond then do". All the images that I use in pictureboxes are in Resources.
I tried something like `if(pictureBox1.Image == Properties.Resources.diamond){}` but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You may need to compare the content of byte arrays that define the data image (colors of pixels).

Comment: How do you set the image in the picture box?

Comment: you dont, you store the information when you put it in

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.diamond;

Comment: Once you got two byte arrays of images (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801275/how-to-convert-image-to-byte-array & http://net-informations.com/q/faq/imgtobyte.html), you can compare byte-per-byte.

Comment: Are you changing the image to some thing else in the code? Why you need to check what image is assigned to picture box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [How to convert image to byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801275/how-to-convert-image-to-byte-array) :

```
var array1 = ImageToByteArray(pictureBox1.Image);
var array2 = ImageToByteArray(Properties.Resources.diamond);

bool isSame = array1.Length == array2.Length;

if ( isSame )
  for ( int index = 0; index < array1.Length; index++)
    if ( array1[index] != array2[index] )
    {
      isSame = false;
      break;
    }

if ( isSame )
{
  ...
}
```

Also : [How to compare two images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647811/how-to-compare-two-images)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much! This solved my problem.